# How can I iterate into arrays with subarrays and display value in <li>?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have the following arrays structure:

**CODE PHP:**

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)  // data element
      1 => string 'https://www.pinterest.com' (length=25) // link
      2 => string '1' (length=1)  // data target
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1) // data element
      1 => string 'https://www.linkedin.com' (length=24)  // link
      2 => string '2' (length=1) // data target
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1) // data element
      1 => string 'https://www.facebook.com' (length=24)  // link
      2 => string '4' (length=1) // data target
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1) // data target
      1 => string 'https://www.twiiter.com' (length=23)  // link
      2 => string '7' (length=1) // data element
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)    // data target
      1 => string 'https://www.instagram.com' (length=25)  // link
      2 => string '9' (length=1)    // data element
```

I want to interate these arrays and display the following values into `<ul>` with `<li>` structure

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($splitArr as $arr) { ?>
        <li><a href="#">$arr[0]</a></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="http://www.pinterest.com" data-element="1" data-target="1">http://www.pinterest.com</a> 
   </li>
   ... etc
</ul>
```

Can you help me please solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are so close... what is the issue

Comment: _“Can you help me please solve this problem?”_ - what actual problem? Simply stating what you “want”, is not a proper problem description - please go see [ask]. You seem to already know how to access specific elements from the second level by their index in the sub-array - so what else are you actually missing? (That you need to `echo` them, if you want to see them in the output?)

Comment: u are swapping target and element indexes in 3 and 4 indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($splitArr as $arr) { ?>
       <li> <a href="<?=$arr[1]?>" data-element="<?=$arr[2]?>" data-target="<?=$arr[0]?>"><?=$arr[1]?></a> </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($splitArr as $arr) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $arr[1]; ?>" data-element="<?php echo $arr[0]; ?>" data-target="<?php echo $arr[2]; ?>">http://www.pinterest.com</a>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change like this

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($splitArr as $key=>$value) { 
       echo '<a href="'.$value[1].'" data-element="'.$value[2].'" data-target="'.$value[0].'">'.$value[1].'</a>

     } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can below below snippet,

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($splitArr as $arr) {?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $arr[1]; ?>" data-element="<?php echo $arr[0]; ?>" data-target="<?php echo $arr[2]; ?>">
                   <?php echo $arr[1]; ?>
                </a>
            </li>
    <?php }?>
</ul>
```